# tuple object with for statement

Tags: python, tuples

Here is my code in Python, I'm trying to print that goal_state, but still I have the problem with tuple: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable 
Thank you!

```
goal_state = [[0,1,2],
           [3,4,5],
           [6,7,8]]

print(goal_state[0])
print(goal_state[1])
print(goal_state[2])

for i in range(0,2):
    print(goal_state[i])

runfile('C:/Users/Patrik/Desktop/isi.py', wdir='C:/Users/Patrik/Desktop')
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-100-16772532c44a>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/Patrik/Desktop/isi.py', wdir='C:/Users/Patrik/Desktop')

File "C:\Users\Patrik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Patrik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
File "C:/Users/Patrik/Desktop/isi.py", line 11, in <module>
for i in range(0,2):

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: You don't show us all of your code. This code works, and there is not a single tuple here.

Comment: I'm using Spyder and that's all of my code... I just want to try to print it.

Comment: Then show us the entire stacktrace.

Comment: You can check now, I added rest of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have assigned some tuple value to variable `range`. Use `del range` to reset it, then `range(0, 2)` will evaluate properly.

Comment: Lol, that's weird but is working. Thank you, Vlad!

Comment: It is easier to not reassign `range` to begin with